# iwl4965 Wifi Microcode SW error detected

Tags: microcode

Ever since I installed Xubuntu 16.04, these error messages appear from time to time on syslog.  It doesn't happen very often but I'd like to know if there's a fix for that.

Thank you!

```
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x82000000.
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 228.61.2.24
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x0002B3E4, count: 5
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Desc                                  Time       data1      data2      line
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: NMI_INTERRUPT_WDG            (0x0004) 3043856388 0x00000002 0x02430000 208
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: pc      blink1  blink2  ilink1  ilink2  hcmd
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: 0x0046C 0x02F3E 0x004C2 0x006DE 0x02FAA 0x0001C
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: FH register values:
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:       FH49_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X0341b800
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:      FH49_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X00340c90
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:                FH49_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X000000b0
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:       FH49_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X80809000
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:        FH49_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X0000003c
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:          FH49_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X02430000
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:   FH49_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:              FH49_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X07ff0002
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0:               FH49_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Can't stop Rx DMA.
ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
```

Wifi adapter details:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Lenovo ThinkPad T61
    Kernel driver in use: iwl4965
    Kernel modules: iwl4965
```

Up to this date, I have found no answer to this issue. Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this issue?

Comment: No, and it hasn't been resolved on Kubuntu 18.04.1 either. I've found posts that say it's a Debian issue but absolutely no solution to it.

Comment: I think you should report this type of issue to the Ubuntu bug tracker to clarify who should be able to fix it. I'm experiencing a similar problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071051/ubuntu-freezes-for-a-few-seconds-with-error-microcode-sw-error-detected

Comment: I see that you are facing the problem using a different driver. This new development clearly shows that both **iwl4965** and **iwlwifi** are having this problem. Other people have already forwarded the problem years ago. I really don't know why it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Correct. Some people have been able to fix it by upgrading the kernel. However, the main problem is that we don't know exactly what is causing this issue in the first place.