# Ubuntu freezes for a few seconds with error "Microcode SW error detected"

Tags: networking, intel-wireless

After installing Ubuntu MATE 16.04 in a Dell G7, I noticed small freezes  and after inspecting the syslog I found errors with "Microcode SW error detected".

This is the relevant syslog output:

```
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735364] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735776] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735785] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735792] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.0
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735801] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000942 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00456D06 | branchlink2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0046064A | interruptlink1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735836] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735854] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFDFFFB2 | data1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735873] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x03010100 | data2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000F0602 | data3
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000118DE | beacon time
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735895] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA12B3C82 | tsf low
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735899] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003E | tsf hi
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735904] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735908] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0004D252 | time gp2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735913] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000022 | uCode version major
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735927] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00489008 | board version
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000001C | hcmd
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00023000 | isr0
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735966] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735979] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x404140C0 | isr3
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.735993] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736003] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A2C001C | last cmd Id
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736012] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000D4 | l2p_control
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000007 | l2p_mhvalid
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736026] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736042] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x12111721 | timestamp
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736053] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000B8B8 | flow_handler
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736222] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000100, count: 7
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000070 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0087D08 | umac branchlink2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac interruptlink1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736246] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac interruptlink2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000800 | umac data1
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736255] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac data2
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000022 | umac major
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac minor
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088628C | frame pointer
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736278] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088628C | stack pointer
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004B014E | last host cmd
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Aug 31 23:24:48 laptop2 kernel: [35714.736295] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348226] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348633] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.0
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348639] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000942 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00456D06 | branchlink2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0046064A | interruptlink1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFB5FFFD | data1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x03000101 | data2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348676] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000F0602 | data3
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFFC6AD0 | beacon time
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA176B719 | tsf low
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003D | tsf hi
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000B5821 | time gp2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348704] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348708] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000022 | uCode version major
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348713] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348722] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00489008 | board version
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000001C | hcmd
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348732] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x82323002 | isr0
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348736] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00004000 | isr1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348741] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348745] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x404140C4 | isr3
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348750] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348754] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0AFE001C | last cmd Id
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348759] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348768] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348773] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348777] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348782] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348786] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x12111721 | timestamp
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348791] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00003838 | flow_handler
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000100, count: 7
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000070 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348959] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348964] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0087D08 | umac branchlink2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac interruptlink1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348973] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac interruptlink2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348978] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000800 | umac data1
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348982] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac data2
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348991] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000022 | umac major
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.348996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac minor
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.349001] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088628C | frame pointer
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.349005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088628C | stack pointer
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.349010] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x005F014E | last host cmd
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.349014] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Aug 31 23:24:50 laptop2 kernel: [35717.349022] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535410] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.0
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000942 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535850] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535856] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535861] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00456D06 | branchlink2
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535866] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0046064A | interruptlink1
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00970142 | data1
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535911] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x03010100 | data2
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535923] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000F0602 | data3
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535931] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFFCE0E9 | beacon time
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA1702092 | tsf low
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003E | tsf hi
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535950] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0004C024 | time gp2
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535959] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000022 | uCode version major
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535964] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535973] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00489008 | board version
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535978] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000001C | hcmd
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535982] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00023000 | isr0
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.535992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536003] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x404141C0 | isr3
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A56001C | last cmd Id
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | wait_event
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536056] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000D4 | l2p_control
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536063] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536068] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000007 | l2p_mhvalid
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536078] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x12111721 | timestamp
Aug 31 23:24:52 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009898 | flow_handler
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536246] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000100, count: 7
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000070 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536255] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536261] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0087D08 | umac branchlink2
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac interruptlink1
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac interruptlink2
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536278] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000800 | umac data1
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536283] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0083A08 | umac data2
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000022 | umac major
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac minor
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088628C | frame pointer
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088628C | stack pointer
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004A014E | last host cmd
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Aug 31 23:24:53 laptop2 kernel: [35719.536324] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
```

For additional context, `sudo lshw -C network` shows the following information:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 10
       serial: 30:24:32:d0:66:f5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=34.0.0 ip=192.168.200.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:ed31c000-ed31ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: enp59s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:bf:64:32:cb:01
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 memory:ed200000-ed23ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

and `lspci | grep 'Network'`

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a370 (rev 10)
```

What should I do? Is this a known issue?

Comment: seems to be a known issue, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1710390) and also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045466/iwlwifi-wifi-microcode-sw-error-detected-ubuntu-18-04-x64)

Comment: Both are similar issues although with different wireless cards, so it is not clear if the root cause is the same. I will try to "fix it" with the workaround provided in the first link

Comment: Unfortunately, the workaround didn't work.

Comment: You can try to find out if the freezing is really related to these errors: disable your WiFi (maybe there is a switch on the laptop, or in the BIOS) and don't use the network for an hour (or use a cable, if possible)

Comment: Yes, good idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: I used cable as you suggested, and there is no error and obviously, no noticeable issues. Immediately after I'm connected to the wifi network, the same errors are occurring again

Comment: What your wifi card ? I guess its the Intel 9560. Can you check if you have the latest `iwlwifi` packages installed ? There seems to have been some [issues in the recent past ](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

Comment: Yes, I was told that this bug is related to PHY and antennas. I will update the question when this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201053). If you have similar problems, file a report after following the instructions in https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/debugging.